# Is it possible to independently develop modules in a multi-module IntelliJ/Gradle project?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I recently learned that I could add modules to an IntelliJ (or Android Studio) project. This provided me with a solution to the problem of showing multiple projects using the IntelliJ Code With Me plugin. I had hoped to use this single multi-module project to independently develop all the projects but I quickly saw that the initial project `settings.gradle.kts` file was modified, thus breaking independence, much to my chagrin.

The development model that I want to impose would have a single Android app that pretty much only uses Android classes. This app would depend on multiple sub-projects (provided in a Gradle dependencies block) each of which is a single, simple project developed using IntelliJ, persisted to GitLab and deployed to Maven Central. Thus all modules are independently developable and deployable.

From time to time, during a remote meetup or review session, I would like to use the Code With Me plugin to view the app project and all its sub-projects together.

My next attempt will be to create a shadow project which is only used by the Code With Me plugin that contains the app project and all the sub-projects as modules. I will need to git update each module. That is not too onerous but if there is a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about creating a shadow project. The workaround is to create an "Empty Project" project type in the IDEA and add these projects as modules (File | New | Module/Module from Existing Source from the main menu) into this project.
Feel free to watch the related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65293/